# SubViews with Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a helloworld scene that I would like to add a subview to.

How is this done in cocos2d? I want to add a subview near the lower part of screen.

I want this view to be controlled by the helloworld scene, hiding and showing the subview as needed.

How is this done in cocos2d?

Thanks

Comment: so, you are new to cocos2d. have you read the programming guide http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index ?

Comment: You should really avoid attempting to use UIKit with Cocos2D in my opinion.  It's a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the subview (probably CCLayer) as a child to the hello world scene.

```
CCLayer* subview = //initialize
[subview setPosition:ccp(X,Y)];

[self addChild:subview];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `CCLayer` as a child to the CCScene or to the main CCLayer inside of it.